# Temporarily saving data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap, android-image

I have a quite large `bitmap` that i have to pass between fragments and use in several different places and from what I know it is a costly operation.

So I thought about saving this bitmap somewhere so that I only have to pass the `URI`. But I don't know how to save that image so that it is saved temporarily - I could save that in internal app storage but if a user closed the app when it's in the background or did something similar, I wouldn't be able to delete it so it's stuck there forever.

Comment: No, not forever as for instance you could delete the file at restart of your app. Or already at closing the activity.

Comment: That't true, not forever, but i have to check every time this way :/

Comment: You program it once and then its done.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving that issue would be to use a `SharedViewModel` for all the fragment that need that image and save the bitmap there.
But this way I have the bitmap taking memory all the time, not only when it is needed.
This could work for smaller bitmaps, I don't know if it is suitable for larger ones.